# is it right to say ' Restrictions extended'

Tags: grammar

I read this title tonight and I got a bit confused about the grammar. Unfortunately, I  always translate the sentence to my mother tongue and it did not make any sense. Should not it be passive like 'Restrictions were extended'

Many Thanks

Comment: Was it in a newspaper headline?

Comment: Yes it is the headline of the news

Comment: Headlines use special language to save space. 'Man, 27, killed dog, court told', not 'A man aged 27 killed a dog, a court has been told'. [Grammar rules for writing headlines](http://englishlessonsbrighton.co.uk/8-grammar-rules-writing-newspaper-headlines/)

Comment: The first time I used this website. I appreciate the good example you have shown me

Comment: As headlinese it means "(The) restrictions **have been** extended".